# Variable variable names in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

There's a lot of topics about variable inside variables in a Windows batch files in here, and I tried to understand them. So I end up with this code, but looks like it's in a infinite loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%a in (RPR SAM) do (
  for /l %%w in (000 iso pic) do (
    set /a a!w!=H:\MyPath\!%%a\!%%a!%%w
  )
)
```

The result should be the following variables:

```
RPR000=H:\MyPath\RPR\RPR000
RPRiso=H:\MyPath\RPR\RPRiso
RPRpic=H:\MyPath\RPR\RPRpic

SAM000=H:\MyPath\SAM\SAM000
SAMiso=H:\MyPath\SAM\SAMiso
SAMpic=H:\MyPath\SAM\SAMpic
```

What am I doing wrong, or, is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you expect?

```
@echo off
for %%a in (RPR SAM) do (
  for %%w in (000 iso pic) do (
    set zzz%%a%%w=H:\MyPath\%%a\%%a%%w
  )
)
set zzz 
pause
```

Comment: Almost, the variables are being called zzzRPRiso, zzzRPRpic , zzzRPR000 and so on... I need them to be named without zzz, because they're accessed by a third party application which I can't control. And if I remove the zzz on the loop it does not set any variable at all.

Comment: It will create the variables just fine if you remove the `zzz` in both places - you just won't see them listed as easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set /a a=0
:@
if 1%1==1 (
set Last=%0
GOTO :@@ 
)
set VarB=%VarB% %1
@shift
goto :@
:@@
set /a a=%a%+1
FOR /F "TOKENS=%a%* DELIMS= " %%G IN ('echo %VarB%') do (
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS= " %%A IN ('echo %%G') do (

set Var%a%=%%G
set VarA%a%=%%H
set VarR=%%G
)
)
if 1%VarR%==1%Last% goto :A
goto :@@
:A
echo |echo %%Var%a%%%
    REM In Batch Scripts use Double Percent on the outside like dealing with a for statement.
    REM In CMD.exe just use echo [The Character Pipe] echo %Var%a%% 
exit
```